# Remove frame borders in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to remove the border of frame that has a lot of check boxes and I tried 'borderstyle 0 - frmborderstylenone' in the frame properties and it is not working. I have shown the frame border in the picture. I have many of these frames in a userform and each of these frames has at least 5 check boxes. kindly help me out

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the BorderStyle to 1 and then back to 0 and it removed it completely.

Comment: Amazing.. worked like a gem :) thank you TheJeebo :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be surprised to learn the picture you provided does not have a `Border`.  What you see is the `SpecialEffect` property set to `fmSpecialEffectSunken`.

You can set the property to `fmSpecialEffectNone` to remove it.  It can be set manually in the project properties window or via code.

Setting the `Border` property to `fmBorderStyleSingle` while using a special effect will set `fmSpecialEffectNone` because borders are special effects are mutually exclusive.  Enabling one will disable the other because you cannot use both at the same time.  This is why setting and then removing the border works.

Comment: All suggestions are well taken. Thank you everyone for the response :)

Comment: @Muni0408  Pretty sure we're all here to help and to learn.... and maybe to help learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Following [TheJeebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11384581/thejeebo) hint, setting the frame properties from code, this doesn't work:

```
Set myForm = New Userform
Set frm = myForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame1", True)
With frm
    .BorderStyle = 0
```

The frame border still there when the UserForm is displayed, but surprisingly this does work:

```
Set myForm = New Userform
Set frm = myForm.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "Frame1", True)
With frm
    .BorderStyle = 1
    .BorderStyle = 0
```

no border now.